# Text View On Touch Listener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'd like to scale a textView with the android gesture recognizer, I inserted a textview with an ontouchlistener that is handled by the activity. I works well, but sometimes the phones sends coordinates that are distant from each other, resulting in a strange behaviour.

```
et.setOnTouchListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("vieww", view.toString() + event.toString());
    return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event, view);
}
```

In the errors, we can see how it jumps from 0.2 to 29 in the x[1] coordinate and this happens occasionally with a distant measure.

```
2019-11-29 11:42:12.001 24190-24190/com.puzio.fantamaster D/vieww: com.puzio.fantamaster.stories.CustomTextView{c403026 V.ED..... ........ 363,1009-717,1151}MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=388.7553, y[0]=67.06885, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, id[1]=1, x[1]=-0.9180603, y[1]=64.4707, toolType[1]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=2, historySize=1, eventTime=185339115, downTime=185338000, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
2019-11-29 11:42:12.018 24190-24190/com.puzio.fantamaster D/vieww: com.puzio.fantamaster.stories.CustomTextView{c403026 V.ED..... ........ 363,1009-717,1151}MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=389.37167, y[0]=67.037476, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, id[1]=1, x[1]=-0.5545349, y[1]=64.32861, toolType[1]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=2, historySize=1, eventTime=185339131, downTime=185338000, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
2019-11-29 11:42:12.035 24190-24190/com.puzio.fantamaster D/vieww: com.puzio.fantamaster.stories.CustomTextView{c403026 V.ED..... ........ 363,1009-717,1151}MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=389.8729, y[0]=67.28259, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, id[1]=1, x[1]=-0.06616211, y[1]=63.908325, toolType[1]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=2, historySize=1, eventTime=185339148, downTime=185338000, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
2019-11-29 11:42:12.051 24190-24190/com.puzio.fantamaster D/vieww: com.puzio.fantamaster.stories.CustomTextView{c403026 V.ED..... ........ 363,1009-717,1151}MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=390.5043, y[0]=67.229004, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, id[1]=1, x[1]=0.2909851, y[1]=63.786743, toolType[1]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=2, historySize=1, eventTime=185339164, downTime=185338000, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
2019-11-29 11:42:12.052 24190-24190/com.puzio.fantamaster D/CustomTextViewww: [{overlay_type=t, overlay_color=FFFFFFFF, overlay_content=abueloooo, overlay_rotation=65.892624, overlay_width=113.86625, overlay_height=23.015692, overlay_x=-6.9331245, overlay_y=41.589497, overlay_background=FFFFFFFF}]
2019-11-29 11:42:12.068 24190-24190/com.puzio.fantamaster D/vieww: com.puzio.fantamaster.stories.CustomTextView{c403026 V.ED..... ........ 363,1009-717,1151}MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=355.4997, y[0]=69.382324, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, id[1]=1, x[1]=29.689026, y[1]=63.908936, toolType[1]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=2, historySize=1, eventTime=185339181, downTime=185338000, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
2019-11-29 11:42:12.070 24190-24190/com.puzio.fantamaster D/CustomTextViewww: [{overlay_type=t, overlay_color=FFFFFFFF, overlay_content=abueloooo, overlay_rotation=65.89123, overlay_width=137.12038, overlay_height=27.968573, overlay_x=-18.560186, overlay_y=39.113056, overlay_background=FFFFFFFF}]
2019-11-29 11:42:12.085 24190-24190/com.puzio.fantamaster D/vieww: com.puzio.fantamaster.stories.CustomTextView{c403026 V.ED..... ........ 363,1009-717,1151}MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=400.99493, y[0]=68.80994, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, id[1]=1, x[1]=-7.1364136, y[1]=61.94348, toolType[1]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=2, historySize=1, eventTime=185339198, downTime=185338000, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
```